# This field is required. Dajngo rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm trying to send put request on my Django rest API server. but my rest API server is giving me this exception again and again `{'user': ['This field is required.']}`

what should i do?

**Django rest framework `serializer.py`**

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ("email", "first_name", "last_name",)
        read_only_fields = ("username",)

    def validate_email(self, email):
        if User.objects.filter(email=email).first() and User.objects.filter(id=self.context.get("request").user.id).first().email != email:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("* Email Already Exist!")

        if not email:
            raise serializers.ValidationError("* Email Adress is Required!")

        return email

class UserProfileSerializer(CountryFieldMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer()
    avatar = AvatarSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ("username",)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        user_validated_data = validated_data.pop('user')
        profile = Profile.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(**validated_data)
        user = User.objects.filter(id=instance.user.id).update(**user_validated_data)
        return Profile.objects.filter(id=instance.id).first()
```

**django rest framework `views.py`**

```
class UserProfileRetrieveUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer

    def get_user_or_404(self):
        return get_object_or_404(User, id=self.request.user.id)

    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Profile, user=self.get_user_or_404())
        return obj
```

**function that is sending put request.**

```
def edit_specific_profile(request, form):
    token = request.session.get('access')

    data = {
        "id": None,
        "user": {
            "email": form.cleaned_data.get("email"),
            "first_name": form.cleaned_data.get("first_name"),
            "last_name": form.cleaned_data.get("last_name")
        },
        "headline": form.cleaned_data.get("headline"),
        "maiden_name": form.cleaned_data.get("maiden_name"),
        "company_name": form.cleaned_data.get("company_name"),
        "proposal_comments": form.cleaned_data.get("proposal_comments"),
        "associations": form.cleaned_data.get("associations"),
        "interests": form.cleaned_data.get("interests"),
        "website": form.cleaned_data.get("website"),
        "location": form.cleaned_data.get("location"),
        "bio": form.cleaned_data.get("bio"),
        "state": form.cleaned_data.get("state"),
        "country": form.cleaned_data.get("country"),
        "date_of_birth": form.cleaned_data.get("date_of_birth"),
    }

    print(data)

    url = settings.AUTHENTICATION_HOST + "accounts/profile/"

    response = requests.put(url, data = data, headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"})

    print(response.json())
```

**and in Django rest framework web interference in raw data**

Django rest framework is expecting

```
{
    "user": {
        "username": "admin",
        "email": "itshamzamirchi@gmail.com",
        "first_name": "Hamza2",
        "last_name": "Lachi"
    },
    "headline": "Test",
    "maiden_name": "test",
    "company_name": "t",
    "proposal_comments": "",
    "associations": "",
    "interests": "",
    "website": "",
    "location": "",
    "bio": "",
    "state": "",
    "country": "",
    "date_of_birth": null
}
```

Comment: Can you add your `UserSerializer` please ? The one used in `UserProfileSerializer `

Comment: @Henri question has been updated with user serializer.

Comment: Thanks I added an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possibility would be to use `required=False` and check if 'user' is present in `validated_data.keys()`.
You can too change the end and use `super()`

```
class UserProfileSerializer(CountryFieldMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):

    user = UserSerializer(required=False)
    avatar = AvatarSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = "__all__"
        read_only_fields = ("username",)

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):
        if 'user' in validated_data.keys():
            user_validated_data = validated_data.pop('user')
            user = User.objects.filter(id=instance.user.id).update(**user_validated_data)            
        return super(UserProfileSerializer, self).update(instance, validated_data)
```

You can modify your view too :

```
class UserProfileRetrieveUpdateAPIView(RetrieveUpdateAPIView):
    serializer_class = UserProfileSerializer
    
    def get_object(self):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__id=self.request.user.id)
        return obj
```

Comment: it's working but only on profile model fields not on user fields

Comment: it's not updating user fields.

Comment: It means your 'user' is not present in your `validated_data`. It is a problem with your request. Why do you use `put` and not `patch` ?

Comment: print(validated_data) -- output `{'headline': 'Tes23t', 'maiden_name': 'test', 'company_name': 't', 'proposal_comments': 're7', 'associations': '3', 'interests': '', 'website': '', 'location': '', 'bio': '', 'state': '', 'country': ''}`

Comment: these is no user in validated data

Comment: In your request, what are you patching ?
requests.put(url, data = data, headers = {"Authorization": f"Bearer {token}"}) => what are the data ?